# Unable to disable soft keyboard in my android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I have in my setting the option which should disable the app soft keyboard as some users could have a device with physical keyboard.

The issue is that everything i'm trying is not working and the soft keyboard is shown anyway,

I've tryed:

adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in my manifest, i've tryed the following code in my fragment:

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val imm: InputMethodManager =
        activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    var view = activity.currentFocus
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = View(activity)
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

which i called in onViewCreated like:

```
hideKeyboard(requireActivity())
```

I've set to all EditText showSoftInputOnFocus:

```
val keyboard = prefs.getBoolean("keyboard", true)
txtBarcode.showSoftInputOnFocus = keyboard
txtQta.showSoftInputOnFocus = keyboard
```

And when showSoftInputOnFocus is set the keyboard doen't appear, but once i type something with the physical keyobard the softkeyboard is shown...

So based on my setting keyboard value (true,false) how can i disable the softkeyboard for the whole applicaiton??

Comment: In my experience Android doesn't show the soft keyboard when using a physical one so you shouldn't have to manually manage it. There are some reports of this happening on certain devices like this one https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42842/samsung-soft-keyboard-keeps-popping-up-when-bluetooth-keyboard-in-use-on-galaxy Have you tried a different device?

Comment: @HenryTwist i'm using a Zebra MC33 and other devices like that, and the soft keyboard is shown in any case...